# Continuity of the function $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{1+(2\sin(x))^{2n}}$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I was studying the continuity of the function:
$f(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{1+(2\sin(x))^{2n}}$

I understood that the function behave  as

$
f(x)=x   \quad2 \sin(x)  \leq 1
 \\
f(x)=0   \quad 2\sin(x)\geq 1
$

So there is a discontinuity point in $\frac{\pi}{6}$

Now come my doubt. In my opinion is a jump discontinuity because goes from $\lim_\limits{x\to{\frac{\pi}{6}-}} f(x)=\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $\lim_\limits{x\to\frac{\pi}{6}+}f(x)=0$.
But my book says that is an essential discontinuity. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The value of $f$ at points where $2\sin x=\pm1$ is $x/2$, to be precise. You're forgetting several other singular points.

Answer (score 2):

This may just be a matter of definitions. Whereas [Wikipedia's definition of  essential discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Essential_discontinuity) excludes jump discontinuities, there appear to be [other definitions of essential discontinuities](http://www.mathwords.com/e/essential_discontinuity.htm) that include them.

Comment: The same site has http://www.mathwords.com/s/step_discontinuity.htm so apparently it partially disagrees with itself.

Comment: It isn't a question of definitions. The definitions are from the book. They are like Wikipedia's one.

Comment: @Tarlo_x: Then it seems that you're right and the book is wrong.